# Log all query in cassandra 3.4.4

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

I'm looking to log all logs in Cassandra 3.4.4 (for instance, to log if query was ok, bad, but also connection timed out or bad credentials). Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Cassandra 3 doesn’t have a feature for that.  However, there is an open source 3rd party plugin that does this.

Check out Ericsson’s Cassandra Query Logger:
https://github.com/Ericsson/ecaudit/

Basically, you download the JAR, add it to `lib/`, reference it in the Cassandra-env.sh, and that should do it.